# How to check how long MySQL query is taking?

Tags: mysql, database, indexing

When I run a query, I don't want it to print to the console.
I just want to see the time.

```
9166 rows in set (0.90 sec)
```

Thats all I want to see, instead of it printing everything.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this simple example

```
mysql> set profiling=1;
mysql> select count(*) from comment;
mysql> select count(*) from message;
mysql> show profiles;

+----------+------------+------------------------------+
| Query_ID | Duration   | Query                        |
+----------+------------+------------------------------+
|        1 | 0.00012700 | select count(*) from comment |
|        2 | 0.00014200 | select count(*) from message |
+----------+------------+------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Caveat:  The 5.6.7 Changelog says "The [SHOW PROFILE](http://dev.mysql.comhttps://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/show-profile.html) and [SHOW PROFILES](http://dev.mysql.comhttps://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/show-profiles.html) statements. Use the Performance Schema instead; see [MySQL Performance Schema](http://dev.mysql.comhttps://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/performance-schema.html). "

Comment: @RickJames, looks like your links are a bit off. They're all linking to `dev.mysql.comhttps//dev.mysql.com`/path

Comment: Strange.  Lop off the redundant info before "http".

Answer (score 3):

You can write your query inside sub-query with `COUNT` to do the trick as:

```
SELECT COUNT(1)
FROM ( SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE ...) a
```

It may slow down your query slightly, as it's doing `COUNT` also but I think its negligible.

For measuring performance of query you can turn on `PROFILES` in MySQL as:

```
SET profiling = 1;
```

For more details about `PROFILES` see [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-profiles.html).

Comment: It says "ERROR 1248 (42000): Every derived table must have its own alias"?

Comment: give any alias to derived table as I have given 'a' at the end

Answer (score 0):

```
$starttime = microtime(true);

//Do your query and stuff here

$endtime = microtime(true);
$duration = $endtime - $starttime; //calculates total time taken
```

Comment: This approach is good for PHP.  However, be aware that the elapsed time will include the roundtrip time between client and server.  Check how much time that is by doing something trivial like `SELECT 1;`